# Internet Explorer engine is not available Error During Sitecore Horizon Installation

Tags: horizon

I've installed Sitecore 9.3 and it is all working fine, I didn't get any errors during installation. After that, I follow the documentation and replaced all parameters in `parameters.ps1` file. But when I run `install.ps1` I got below Error -

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not
available, or Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete. Specify the UseBasicParsing parameter
and try again.
At D:\scdumps\sc93\Sitecore Horizon 9.3.0\Public\Install-FeatureIntegrationPackage.ps1:92 char:5
+     Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreCM -WorkingDirectory $wrkm ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:12
Invoke-WebRequest : The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not available, or
Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete. Specify the UseBasicParsing parameter and try again.
At D:\scdumps\sc93\Sitecore Horizon 9.3.0\Extensions\sitecore-cm.psm1:62 char:9
+         Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $siteURL -TimeoutSec 600
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletIEDomNotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestComman
   d
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was showing that the `Internet Explorer engine is not available`.
But I had installed this on my system from the beginning. So try to find some other solutions and most of them were saying to update the exiting script by adding 
`-UseBasicParsing` parameter. Since I was installing Horizon first time so I was afraid of updating this.

But real problem was that Internet Explorer Browser was not launched properly on my system, every time I launched IE it was asking me for the first-launch configuration and I always clicked on `ask me later`. All we need to set this configuration and click "Ok". I will recommend selecting the recommended setting from the dialog box-

[image]